# How to check all check boxes by checking one?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check all check boxes when "selectall" check box is selected

I have tried some codes to get it to work but still not working for me.

when I click on the main check box nothing happens.

here is what I a have done so far

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    if(   $('#selectall').is(':checked')  ){

        $.each($('input[name=activitie]'){
            $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true)
        }

    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: As written above, `if($('#selectall').is(':checked'))` tests the initial state of the element. You need to attach a `change` handler to apply the test (and associated code) when the user changes the element's state.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot is correct, you can use '.click()' and then test the state, which I did in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shameless self-promotion: [there's a jQuery plugin for that](http://mjball.github.io/jQuery-CheckAll/). In your case, I think this will do the trick:

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectall').checkAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
});
```

Without seeing some markup, however, I can't say for sure...

Answer (score 0):

You need something to detect when the state of the checkbox with id 'selectall' is changed, and then determine if it is being checked or not. I've updated your code and fixed a few of your other errors:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
        if ($("#selectall").is(":checked")) {
            $.each($('input[name=activitie]'), function () {
                $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Additionally, if you want them to all uncheck when 'selectall' is unchecked, you can just add an else clause with that same `$.each` just with the `.prop` setting the checkboxes to unchecked, or false. There's probably a simpler way to do this with some kind of plugin, but I suspect this should help.

I've put together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmMfn/) which should help demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectall").on("change", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("input[type=checkbox][name=activitie]").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
});
```